# What is First Three Instructions in the Disassembled Code

Tags: assembly, disassembly, instructions

What is the meaning of the first three commands being the same after most programs are disassembled? What is the meaning of the first three commands being the same after most programs are disassembled?

For example, below you can see the disassembled code of exe:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push -1
```

Or when I disassemble another exe, it looks like the following:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0x3f4
```

Comment: The first two instructions are the prologue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post pictures to text. Please read the help section [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which specifically says "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc."

Comment: @Homer512 I can't show the picture directly because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @MargaretBloom So what is "prologue"? I'll accept if you answer the question.

Comment: You're not supposed to use pictures to begin with! You should copy-and-paste the disassembled code into your question

Comment: They didn't put the picture button there for decoration! I could have put a picture, so I did @Homer512

Comment: If you want help, you should follow the rules. I directly quoted the help section to you. Please follow it. The proper use of images on SO is for diagrams, plots, etc. Not code snippets

Comment: I changed it, thx. Can you answer if you know the answer to close the subject @Homer512?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue_and_epilogue